StackExchange.Redis JSON Extension Set and Get of a Json object array
I have a C# EventJSON object whose Json is like following, sample simplified, there is an eventguid, eventtype, resourcename, codes, ...  but example below will do it.  we store those in a Json NoSQL DB but I want to use Redis for a write thru cache and be more responsive to certain events that cause triggering, notification, aggregation ...
{ "objguid" : "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "eventtime": "2024-08-21T13:05:09"}

//That same "objguid" might get 2nd and 3rd events 
{ "objguid" : "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "eventtime": "2024-08-21T13:05:14"}
{ "objguid" : "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "eventtime": "2024-08-21T12:07:32"}

I think I want to use Redis Json.  In StackExchange.Redis when a new EventJson comes in I
check if objguid document exists and add a serialized empty array.  (There are try catches around this also.
eventJSON[] emptyarr = { };
eventJSON j = new eventJSON("01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "2024-08-21T13:05:09");
if (cachedb.JSON().Set(j.objGuid, "$", NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emptyarr), When.NotExists))
{ //great }
else 
{ //handle that if problem fail or already there}

if (cachedb.JSON().ArrAppend(j.objGuid, "$", j, When.Exists))
{ //great }
else
{ //handle that if problem}

//the same thing would occur for other EventJsons
eventJSON j = new eventJSON("01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "2024-08-21T13:05:09");
//execute above stuff now that objGuid key would have 2 events
eventJSON j = new eventJSON("01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef", "2024-08-21T13:05:09");
//execute above stuff now that objGuid key would have 3 events


Id like to get the above into List js but have struggled mightily with
RedisResult type.  I think probably issue is in how I am writing but what is a good way to do so.
RedisResult gpredisresult = cachedb.JSON().Get(passedinObjGuid,"$")
eventJSON[] js = new eventJSON[]();
//magic sauce ???, nothing seems to work


I figured it out and am able to deserialize back to List, js, with
List js = NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(cachedb.JSON().Get(passedinObjGuid).ToString());   //note get does not have a path
